# How to save MFC CImage in .WMF file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How to save MFC CImage in a .WMF file? If I use CImage.Save method to save it in .WMF format I am getting the error "save failed:80004005 - Unspecified error".

Is there any other way to save MFC CImage in .WMF format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to save it? According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06f3fhw.aspx), `CImage` only supports BMP, PNG, JPG or GIF. You might like to [read this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6879/How-to-use-GDI-to-save-image-in-WMF-EXIF-or-EMF-fo) too.

Comment: Thanks Roger for the reply.Then whether I have to use GDI+ to save CImage in .WMF format?Is there any other way to convert CBitmap into .WMF format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CImage` does not support vector graphics like **Enhanced Metafile Format (EMF)** and **Windows Metafile Format (WMF)** by design. It is just a wrapper class around `Image` class from **GDI+** that does support raster image formats only: **JPEG, GIF, BMP**, and Portable Network Graphics (**PNG**) formats.

Here is the way to save EMF/WMF files based on GDI+:

```
Bitmap* pBitmap;
...
// do some paintings on pBitmap
...
CStringW sFileName = L"c:\\Files\Image.emf";

CDC* pDC = GetDC();
Metafile* pMetaFile = new Metafile(sFileName, pDC->m_hDC);
Graphics graphics(pMetaFile);
graphics.DrawImage(pBitmap, 0, 0, pBitmap->GetWidth(), 
                                  pBitmap->GetHeight());
```

Comment: I am viewing a WMF file using CImage and I rotated that image to 90 degree. Now I want to save it again in WMF file.How to achieve it?

Comment: This functionality is not supported by `CImage`. You shoud use GDI+ Bitmap class instead.